# How to change status bar style during launch on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

When I launch my app, it shows the launch image and a black status bar. How can I change it so the status bar is light during launch? I have set the status bar appearance to light in my AppDelegate didFinishLoading method, and it works for the rest of the app.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To your **Info.plist** file add this key-value pair:

```
UIStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

The default (black) value is `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`.

You can also append `~iphone` or `~ipad` to the key.

Comment: To those viewing this on a mobile device who were confused like I was: that is a tilde, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 19):

There are [2 steps](http://samwize.com/2015/01/13/uistatusbar-with-light-content-style-not-working-pitfall/):

1. This is usually what developers know how to do – Under Target settings > General > Status Bar Style > Change to Light. This will effect the Info.plist to include `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.
2. **This step is often missed out** – In Info.plist, add `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set to NO

Comment: I only have the options: "Hide during application launch" and "Requires full screen". No bar style present.

Comment: @NicolasMiari If you don't see it, then you have to add it. Click on the + at the row.

Comment: I did just that for the .plist. I was talking about the target info pane.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Both steps are about the Info.plist.

Comment: I dont see the Change to light setting in XCode 8 - screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5aF5OG2.png - may you please advise

Answer (score 11):

Just define this method in any view or file you want:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

// swift 
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Comment: I did this but nothing change. Any suggest? @msurguy

Comment: "during launch" - this is for per-view basis.

Comment: This works for changing status bar style on different views, not during Launch (which is what the OP asked)

Comment: This is by far the worst way to change status bar appearance, requiring you to copy this code on every single viewController, or create a subclass, both of which are far inferior to the .plist approach

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` wasn't a possible option. I set `Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)` as value for the key `Status bar style` in my .plist and the result was a white status bar.

Comment: Same for me, strange. I found that any value other than the default one resulted in a light status bar content similar to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Comment: This option is not present in Xcode 5, you have to type it manually.

Comment: If you click the field rather than showing the options you can just enter any value you like. I just pasted it in and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Works on iOS7 and iOS8

You need to set in your **Info.plist** file property for key 
`Status bar style`:

1. Set `Opaque black style` or `Transparent black style (alpha of
   0.5)` for *White* status bar
2. Set `Gray style (default)` to set *Black* status bar color.

It looks like you set Background style for Status Bar and XCode understand which color of status bar need to choose. Dark background - white status bar, light background - black status bar

Answer (score 0):

```
**

 - You must take care of these three things:

**

**- In info.plist file**
Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES

**- In your view controller** in which you want change color of status bar
add this [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate] in viewDidLoad

**- Lastly, add this method**
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
      return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

Note: If you want to set color of statusBar for all the View Controllers then steps are
**- In info.plist file**
Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES

**- Then add this in appDelegate**
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; // **It is deprecated in iOS 9**
```