# Hiding statusbar in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I tried to hide status bar in iOS7 by putting this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

in delegate or in mainview

But it's not working!

It was working in iOS6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/cant-hide-ios-7-status-bar/18980833#18980833

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either set *"View controller-based status bar appearance"* to NO in your info plist or add this code in your view controllers:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: including this methods generates the error message "user of undeclared identifier prefersStatusBarHidden

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your Info.plist:

UIStatusBarHidden

UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

or follow this link http://www.openfl.org/developer/forums/general-discussion/iphone-5ios-7-cant-hide-status-bar/

Comment: It works fine on iphone but the status bar is displayed on ipad.

Answer (score 0):

In a viewController where you want to hide status bar add:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

In viewDidLoad

```
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
```

In app *-info.plist

View controller-based status bar appearance set to YES

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your iOS target -> Info, add View controller-based status bar appearance and set the value as NO.

It worked for me in iOS7. I have also set "status bar initially hidden" property to YES

Answer (score 0):

```
//viewDidload
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
// iOS 7
[self prefersStatusBarHidden];
[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
// iOS 6
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}




// Add this Method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
```

this wil work ..hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your apps plist file add a row call it " **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance**" and set it to NO

from http://www.openfl.org/developer/forums/general-discussion/iphone-5ios-7-cant-hide-status-bar/, mgiroux's solution

Answer (score 0):

In the Plist add the following properties.

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES

View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

[image]

now the status bar will hidden.