# How to hide status bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have tried setting the following in my app `.plist` file:

`View controller-based status bar appearance: NO`

And while this removes it from my initial view controller, once I go to another view and come back with my navigation controller, it comes right back and this time it does not disappear. Also, I don't see why it would matter but I have also set the status bar under simulated metrics to "None" but that doesn't seem to help. I know i am going to have the navigation bar but the status bar I need gone.

[image]

How can I get this done? **Please provide a detailed answer, sample code would be great!**

Update: This is NOT a duplicate solution as I have tried all other solutions and NONE seem to work for me. Most recently I tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Again, with no results. When the app initially launches a status bar is NOT present, after the user visits another view, the status bar is now present in the 2 and other views and does not go away. Even if you go back to the main view.

Comment: you've set into the others controller some staff for your navigation bar?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano yes, but nothing about the `status bar`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981256/hiding-statusbar-in-ios7/18981448#18981448

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried all of the suggestions that were posted here, unfortunately what happened here was a small mistake, in my `viewDidLoad` I had:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

But in my `viewWillAppear` I had:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];`

So this was just an issue of overriding, problem fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

To hide status bar:

if [View controller-based status bar appearance: NO]: in AppDelegate.m call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

else: in every view controller

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work for me, please see updated post

Comment: show more code in your second view. Maybe some code change the status bar hidden property indirectly.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES]; worked for me. Thought I have set View controller-based status bar appearance: NO already

Answer (score 2):

Use this method in the View Controller which you'd like the Status Bar hidden:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work for me, please see updated post

Answer (score 2):

Try this 2 steps:

1. In .Plist file of project set the property:

View controller-based status bar appearance = NO;

and 
2.In all view controller's .m file in viewDidLoad method put this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work for me, please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

// In iOS7 this gets called and hides the status bar so the view does not go under the top iPhone
// status bar

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
      return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

none of these work for me.
when i try this method i get the message "use of undeclared identifier preferstatusbarHidden

```
include - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
      return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to do anymore. I tried setStatusBarHidden, prefersHiddenStatusBar and still no results. Finally i have went through the below you tube link :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtpBXdMSqRQ

It worked for me.