# Status Bar in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I use an `UITableViewController` into a `Navigation Controller` that comes up when an `UIButton` pressed. When the button has been pressed the `TableViewController` comes up without status bar. If i select a cell of the `TableViewController` and then getBack the Status Bar appears properly. I don't know the reason that this happens. I want the Status Bar to appear every time. I tried to set Status Bar from StoryBoard but it did't work. I also tried a lot of solutions programmatically from here.

This is the part of Storyboard that shows the `TableViewController` and the options that have been selected.

[image: Storyboard]

This is the wrong result:

[image: wrong]

If I select a cell and get back to the `TableViewController` I have this result:

[image: right]

I want to have the result of third pic every time.

P.S. In my .plist file I have View controller-based status bar appearance set to YES.

I have added to my `viewDidLoad` this Line:

```
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And below of `viewDidLoad` this method:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

And it shows only the battery life.

Comment: are you check viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear method ? may be there is anything wrong.

Comment: @iPatel thanks for the response. Yes, i have checked these methods but there is not something that handles with status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem in future, this is the answer.

**Step 1:** Add this to your .plist file.

View controller-based status bar appearance ---> NO

**Step 2:** These two lines to your appDelegate into **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that explains well how to set the status bar ViewController based: [iOS 7 and later: set status bar style per view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013975/ios-7-set-status-bar-style-per-view-controller)

Comment: Thanks Tijn but i have tried all of them and they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing code about related to statusBar in `viewDidLoad` and `ViewWillAppear` Then fix it by using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` write this code in `ViewWillAppear` method.