# IOS StatusBar All Black

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

I'm working on an app made ​​by other people.

When I open the app, the status bar is completely black.

I attach a screenshot. [image: Screenshot with Status Bar Black]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like there is now "view" behind your view which has set a background color. If you want that black statusbar, but a white font, you have to change that in your project settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status Bar in UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554202/status-bar-in-uitableviewcontroller)

Comment: It works! sorry but I had not seen this post.