# Apple rejection for black bar on top of ipad screen for an iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, appstore-approval

I submitted the app to app store which is optimized only for iPhone. My app got rejected, the reason by the apple team was:
  The black bars on top/bottom of the screens were present and didn’t comply with guideline 2.10.

According to 2.10 guide line:2.10: iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution.

I tested on iPad too,when the app runs on the iPad,both retina and non-retina devices showing the black bar on top of the iPad screens.

I placed the default launch image sizes 320 * 480, 640 * 960, 640 * 1136 but still its showing the black bar on the iPad screen.

I found the status bar not showing on the iPad non-retina device running with iOS7.0.4 and but showing on the iPad retina devices.

My questions were : 
a.why status bar for an iPhone app not showing on iPad non-retina running with iOS7.0
b.How to solve the issue of black bar on top of iPad devices(retina and non-retina) but not showing on the iPhone app.
c.May be because of status bar ,the black bars on the iPad screen.

My app is only optimized for iPhone but compatible to iPod touch,iPad,iPhone.Deployment Target is 8.1.Please any help to solve this issue . Thanks...

Comment: You can check my similar problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22554202/2838161 My app has been approved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with iOS 7.X iPad devices. I can't currently find source of this problem, however the solution was to use following code in your **root** view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

}
```

Nothing else helps for me - not overriding preffersStatusBarHidden, nor setting plist file.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply,but status bar required for the iPhone.

Comment: Well you could make a runtime check if it's a iPhone or iPad. However you problem appears to be different and you probably should find another solution.