# How to control the StatusBar style with code in Swift3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

I use the code：

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

and I add

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key><false/>
```

in Info.plist.

But the StatusBar still is black style! Why?

Comment: You done need to use Overrite method in Appdelegate : `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` just put the code of line : UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

Comment: @NitinGohel, please, do not suggest the code that's been deprecated. Setting the status bar style programmatically as you are suggesting has been deprecated on iOS 9.0. While it may work for the current version of iOS, in any future release, it may not.

Comment: does it really matters :) @FahriAzimov then please post your answer for the help instead of wasting of your time :)

Comment: Yes, it does matter. You should not teach the beginner to start development with deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because in `Info.plist` you have specified `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key><false/>`. Change it that key to `true`, and it'll work. Main idea behind that key is, when it's true, application looks in your view controllers code for the status bar style for the implementation of `preferredStatusBarStyle` (for status bar style) and `prefersStatusBarHidden` (for if it should hide status bar for this view controller). And, when the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key is false, application looks for the global settings defined in `General` section of the target preferences (choose project file in project navigator in xcode).

Also, you have to keep in mind that, when your view controller is on containers like `UINavigationController` or `UITabbarController`, in order to change the status bar appearance, you have to extends those containers (write extension), and override `preferredStatusBarStyle` property.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013975/ios-7-and-later-set-status-bar-style-per-view-controller) answer on SO as well.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 3**

UINavigationController overrides the view controller its preferred statusbar style. You can give control back to the view controller by subclassing the UINavigationController:

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {

var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle?

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyle ?? .default
}
```

And then you're able to set the statusBarStyle property in the view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let navigationController = navigationController as? BaseNavigationController {
        navigationController.statusBarStyle = preferredStatusBarStyle
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default // any style you want
}
```