# Unable to change status bar style

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a `UIViewController` **VC**, which embedded in `UINavigationController` **NAV**. The `NavigationController` is embedded in `UITabBarController` **TAB**. Now, I need every view controller in my app but **VC** to have `.default` status bar style. **VC** has to have `lightContent` status bar style.

What I’ve done to achieve the desired effect:

1. Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `Info.plist` to **YES**.
2. Overriden `preferredStatusBarStyle` property for every view controller that can be displayed by **NAV** including **VC**.
3. Put `setNeedsStatusBarUpdate()` into `viewDidLoad()` of every view controller that can be displayed by **NAV** including **VC**.

Such an approach resulted in nothing.

Since **TAB** is `initial view controller` inside my `Main.storyboard` and everything is essentially displayed through it, I thought that maybe I can change status bar through it. So I’ve written the following inside **TAB** description:

```
//  MARK: Status bar
///
private var requiredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .default
//
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { get { return self.requiredStatusBarStyle } }
///
func setStatusBarStyle(_ style: UIStatusBarStyle)
{
    requiredStatusBarStyle = style
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

And then invoked `setStatusBarStyle` method of **TAB** by every view controller that can be displayed by **NAV** including **VC** in `viewWillAppear` method. This resulted in nothing as well. Funny thing is invoking `setStatusBarStyle` inside **TAB’s** `viewDidLoad` does nothing too.

Well, if it's not **TAB** that is preventing me from changing style, maybe **NAV** is? So I've made the following extension:

```
struct UINavigationControllerExtensionKeys
{
    static var UIStatusBarStyleKey: UInt8 = 0
}

extension UINavigationController
{
    private var requiredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
    {
        get
        {
            guard let style = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UINavigationControllerExtensionKeys.UIStatusBarStyleKey) as? UIStatusBarStyle else
            {
                return .default
            }
            return style
        }
        set (style)
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UINavigationControllerExtensionKeys.UIStatusBarStyleKey, style, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { get { return self.requiredStatusBarStyle } }

    func setStatusBarStyle(_ style: UIStatusBarStyle)
    {
        requiredStatusBarStyle = style
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }        
    }
}
```

And then invoked `setStatusBarStyle` method of **NAV** by every child view controller of it in `viewWillAppear` method. No luck as well.

It is obvious that I'm overcomplicationg things here. But for some reason answers poroposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013975/ios-7-and-later-set-status-bar-style-per-view-controller) do not work for me. I am lost here people. Please help.

Comment: first of all, `setNeedsStatusBarUpdate` takes into account your current view controller that is presented. so if you call it in `viewDidLoad`, I would expect that at that moment the view controller is not yet presented, thus the status bar style of the presenting view controller will be used..

Comment: second, your second approach seems to be like hacking it, which I would not recommend.. which ios versions are you supporting? don't you happen to have another window overlaying current screen (I had a problem like this)?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I am supporting iOS 11 only. I am using `LNPopupController` to display popups through **TAB**. It doesn't matter whether popup is displayed though: status bar style is `.default` at all times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I need every view controller in my app but VC to have .default
>   status bar style. VC has to have lightContent status bar style.

For me, you're merely giving yourself a headache with your approaches. Here's my take and it will be lot easier.

1. Make a `LightBaseViewController: UIViewController` or whatever base class name you want for all the viewControllers you want to have the light status bar, and put this in `LightBaseViewController`'s `viewWillAppear`:

   ```
   UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
   ```
2. Then of course make a `DarkBaseViewController` and make the status bar dark by making `statusBarStyle` property back to default.

   ```
   UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
   ```
3. Subclass either the dark or light base view controllers.
4. Finally, set this property to NO in your info.plist:

   ```
   View controller-based status bar appearance
   ```

Hope this helps.