# Getting rid of the abominable status bar is not that easy as it seems on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have this app compiled for iOS 6.0 running on iOS 7.

I am trying to get rid of the status bar and I am almost there.

I have added this to info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
Status bar is initially hidden = YES
```

I have added this code to the rootViewController

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;

}
```

Everything is fine. The app loads without the status bar but as soon as I present the UIImagePickerController from the rootViewController the status bar is back, even after the picker dismisses.

Yes, I have subclassed the UIImagePickerController and added the prefersStatusBarHidden to the class, just to see, but nothing changed.

How do I get rid of this abomination. Please save me.

---

EDIT: no,

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this exact same problem in my app. Solution that worked - Assuming that the view controller that shows the UIImagePickerController implements the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol. Implement this protocol method -

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: you have to be patient in these cases cause answers cannot be accepted  in the first 6 minutes... now it is accepted.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded impatient. I wasn't aware of the 6 minutes rule.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No problem. I think the rule applies when the question is fresh and the answer comes within that time frame.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: [How to hide iOS status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/cant-hide-ios-7-status-bar)

and these new methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden