# Remove status bar programmatically in imagePickerController IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I need to remove the status bar when take a photo y try this but not works

**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];**

```
- (IBAction)botonCamara:(id)sender {


    // Make sure camera is available
    if ([UIImagePickerController
         isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Camera Unavailable"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    if (imagePicker == nil)
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    }
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

#pragma mark - delegate methods

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, nil, nil , nil);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the status bar hidden completely do this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        // iOS 7
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    } else {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

// Add this Method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many ways and I think this is the easiest way to hide status bar programmatically.

```
- (void)showStatusBar {
    UIWindow *statusBarWindow = [(UIWindow *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"];
    CGRect frame = statusBarWindow.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    statusBarWindow.frame = frame;
}
- (void)hideStatusBar {
    UIWindow *statusBarWindow = [(UIWindow *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"];
    CGRect frame = statusBarWindow.frame;
    CGSize statuBarFrameSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size;
    frame.origin.y = -statuBarFrameSize.height;
    statusBarWindow.frame = frame;
 }
```

My dev environment: XCode 6.6.1 on Yosemite 10.10.1., for iOS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

In presentViewController completion block set status bar hidden and in dismissviewcontroller's completion unhide the status bar

Comment: not work =( and try this    "  [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];}];  "