# Instantiate several draggable tiles from Storyboard - test code and screenshots attached

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

In Xcode 5 I have created [a single view iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/DragTiles) and checked it into GitHub.

I would like to display 5 draggable tiles with random letters and their values.

I would prefer to define the tile inside the Storyboard and then instantiate it (5 times) from there - because this way it is easy for me to edit the tile (for example move the labels inside the tile).

Currently my project looks like this (here [fullscreen of Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15bd5.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

At the moment have just one tile in the Storyboard and it is draggable:

[image: app screenshot]

I have added a `Tile` class, but **don't know how to connect its outlets** (because I can only ctrl-drag to the [ViewController.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/ViewController.h), but not to the [Tile.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.h)):

Here [Tile.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.h):

```
@interface Tile : UIView

// XXX How to connect the outlets?
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *letter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *value;

@end
```

And [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.m):

```
#import "Tile.h"

static NSString* const kLetters =  @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ";
static UIImage* kTile;
static UIImage* kDragged;

@implementation Tile

+ (void)initialize
{
    // do not run for derived classes
    if (self != [Tile class])
        return;

    kTile    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tile"];
    kDragged = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dragged"];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSString* randomLetter = [kLetters substringWithRange:[kLetters rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:random()%[kLetters length]]];
        int randomInteger = (int)arc4random_uniform(10);

        _background.image = kTile;
        _letter.text = randomLetter;
        _value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", randomInteger];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Finally [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/ViewController.m):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

static int const kNumTiles = 5;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumTiles; i++) {
        // TODO: add a Tile to the VC here
    }
}

- (IBAction)dragTile:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIView *tile = recognizer.view;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:[tile superview]];

        [tile setCenter:CGPointMake(tile.center.x + translation.x,
                                    tile.center.y + translation.y)];

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:tile.superview];

        // TODO: instead of tile.png display dragged.png with shadow
    }
}

@end
```

In the latter file, I don't know

1. **How to instantiate 5 tiles from the Storyboard?**
2. **How to display shadow (the `dragged.png`) when dragging a tile**?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Fogmeister (thanks!) I have added a new file Tile.xib

(Selected in Xcode menu: File -> New -> File... -> User Interface -> View)

Then I've set the Custom Class to `Tile`, but where can I set the (square) dimensions?

[image: Xcode screenshot]

(Here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU94j.png))

**UPDATE 2:**

For `Tile.xib` I've set `Size` to Freeform, `Drawing` to Opaque and dimensions to 100 x 100 (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol4JE.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

**Why does my custom `UIView` have white corners?** How to make the background transparent?

[image: app screenshot]

Also I wonder, how to switch of the display of the battery in Interface Builder?

Comment: The battery is the status bar. You can hide the status bar in code but not in the interface builder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/cant-hide-ios-7-status-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to instantiate 5 tiles from the storyboard.**

I think the thing to realise here is that storyboards are not the solution for everything but rather should be used with the suite of tools that already existed.

For instance. Creating multiple instances of views in this way is not something that can be done very well using Storyboards. Storyboards should be thought of as providing the overall backbone of the app.

To do this I'd do it one of two ways...

**First Way**

Create a new NIB file called `Tile.xib` and layout your single Tile view in there. Connect the outlets up to the Tile class file. Now in your view controller you can load the `Tile` class using the nib for layout...

```
Tile *tile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Tile" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
tile.frame = //blah
[self.view addSubview:tile];
```

**Second Way**

Or forget the nib and load the Tile view all in code in your Tile.m file. Then load it like...

```
Tile *tile = [[Tile alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
[self.view addSubview:tile];
```

**How to display shadow (the dragged.png) when dragging a tile?**

For this you need to set the shadow on the layer of the tile view...

```
tile.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
tile.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
// etc...
```

You can read more about shadows here...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW78

**Edited after comment**

To do this I would have a BOOL property on Tile.h called something like `isDragging`. Or even an enum called `TileState` with `TileStateDragging` and `TileStateStatic`.

Then have a method...

```
- (void)setDragging:(BOOL)dragging
{
    _dragging = dragging;

    if (_dragging) {
        //set to the shadow image.
    } else {
        //set the none shadow image.
    }
}
```

**Some other things to note**

Currently you have code inside `initWithFrame` of the `Tile` class but you are loading the class using a nib (storyboard in this case). This will run the method `initWithCoder` not `initWithFrame` so this code will never get run.

If you want to run code when the class is created you might be best using the method `awakeFromNib` instead.

Comment: +1 thank you, I will try this out. For the shadow I actually mean: how to display **dragged.png** instead of the **tile.png**?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I've edited about updating the shadow.

Comment: I've added a Tile.xib, but it is rectangle? Could you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Set the size to free form. At the moment it is set to portrait. Then you can resize it.

Comment: +1 thanks. Last question please: how to make the background of my custom `UIView` transparent? Currently my tile has opaque white corners - please see the updated question.

Comment: On the right of your Interface Builder screenshot. Half way down. `Background : White Color` change this to `Clear Color`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be solved but I'd still put in my 2 pennies and show you another solution just so that you have a complete picture. You can instantiate a `UICollectionView` in the storyboard and define a `UICollectionViewCell` prototype inline (in the storyboard). The cell is also a regular view so you can put your complete tile view hierarchy in there (all in the storyboard). You will then need to define a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass that will provide layout attributes for the tiles (those can change over time and may be animated just like any other views). The use of collection view will impose a structure on your code that will:

1. scale to any number of tiles,
2. support tasks like animated insertion and deletion of the tiles (you still need to write code in your layout subclass but all the APIs are already defined for you and you don't need to invent the design),
3. separate the layout code from game logic (which is of course not exclusive to this solution but still nice to get without even thinking of it :).

This looks like an overkill for this particular toy project but you might need to consider collection view for more complex situations.