# iOS status bar overlaps with webView

Tags: ios

i have an webView and my problem is that the status bar overlaps my webView.

i already tried the top 2 solutions of this topic:

but it didnt work.
[Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

this is how it looks[image]

any1 has an idea?

my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://bda-bawue.de";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Please show the code you actually used from the provided link.

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"url here";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

Answer (score 0):

You should add this value to plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO". Probably, it is not in your plist file then you should create it.

then type basically: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`
in viewDidLoad method or somewhere else

[How to hide iOS 7 status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar)

Comment: "View controller-based status bar appearance" where can i find this?

Comment: You should add it in your Info.plist file

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: no but it wouldnt fix it anyways since i dont want to hide the bar just want my webView to be below it..