# webview overlaps with status bar only on first load

Tags: ios, swift, webview

The status bar overlaps with the top of my webview, exactly how it looks in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117639/ios-status-bar-overlaps-with-webview//).
However my situation is different from his, because the overlap is only present at the very first load of the webivew, before any of these things happen:

Things that will make the webview spaced properly:

- I switch away from the tab of the webview, and switch back
- I press any of the js buttons on the page
- I rotate the device

[Example vid of 1 and 2 on the list](https://gfycat.com/WideeyedSpeedyHarrier)

In the video, it starts with showing wikipedia improperly spaced, but once I press the sidebar button, it fixes the spacing. Then I scroll to stackoverflow.com, it is improperly spaced, but when I scroll away and come back it fixes itself.

I have all of my webviews constrained with `Webview.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom`

It happens with classes as simple as this:

```
class testweb: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         let url = NSURL (string: "https://stackoverflow.com")
         let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
         webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }
}
```

It happened before I added the animation.
It happens in the simulator, on a real device, and on both iOS 8 and 9

Any ideas?

Comment: Very useful info, but it really would be helpful if you would tell us _all_ about your web view's constraints.

Comment: Also: in your view controller in the storyboard, does it help if you check the Adjust Scroll View Insets checkbox in the Attributes inspector?

Comment: That check box was already checked, and unchecking it did not change anything.

Comment: @matt these are the constraints on that view. [here](http://i.imgur.com/MDqiB5M.png)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, how did you solve this?

Comment: @Franck I never did. Sorry