# How to hide the status bar programmatically in iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8

Just like the question says, I need to hide status + navigation bar when user taps. So far, navigation bar was easy. Cann't find a way to do the same with status bar.

By the way, tried

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
```

but no luck yet

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should  add this key/value pair to your project's Info.plist.

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

[image]

After that,calling

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
```

or

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade) // with animation option.
```

This post gives more details > [How to hide iOS status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar)

Comment: i would like just to tell you Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar) for more details.

Comment: it's deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: @SatnamSync if you look at the date this answer was posted, you'll notice that iOS 9 was not yet released at that time. If you have a better answer, please feel free to answer this question yourself.