# How to hide status bar gradually in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view controller. When user scroll the table up, I want to hide iphone status bar(the top one which includes battery, WIFI etc.) gradually. I know how to hide the status bar by implementing prefersStatusBarHidden() method. But it doesn't hide it with the table scrolling up. So I want it to be kind of part of the table. It should be able to move with the table moving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to hide status bar on iOS, with animation and resizing root view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624695/proper-way-to-hide-status-bar-on-ios-with-animation-and-resizing-root-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to move the status bar; it is either visible or hidden. However, you can get around this by replacing the status when the `UITableView` is about to be scrolled with a `UIView` containing a screenshot that includes the status bar.

I would start with the [`UIScrollViewDelegate.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) Since the `UITableViewDelegate` is a subclass of the `UIScrollViewDelegate,` you can, in your view controller, set your `UITableView`'s delegate to `self.` With this, you can now listen to scrolling movements.

When the `UITableView` is at the top and the user is scrolling down, I would recommend to take a screenshot of the status bar, add it to a `UIView`, and move that said view up at the same speed as the `UITableView` is moving (see the `UIScrollViewDelegate` documentation for help). Likewise, when scrolling to the top, I would have the view move down to the position of the status bar, then remove the view, and set the status bar visible.

With this method, you have the appearance of the status moving up and down with the table view.

Answer (score 2):

initially you get scroll direction of UItableview , then set as BOOL value based on direction

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y > 0)
{
    print("up")
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)  //.Slide
}
else
{
    print("down")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Fade)  //.Slide
}
}
```

> UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden is deprecated in iOS9

**Choice-2**

```
 crete one global Value for get the current position
var hide:Bool = false

 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y > 0)
{
    print("up")
   hide = true

}
else
{
    print("down")
   hide = false

}
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}


override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return hide
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: It works but it is not hidden with the table scroll up.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271271/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-programmatically-in-ios-8