# how to hide the status bar in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, statusbar

In my application in ios8 status bar is hiding.But in iOS7 displaying the status bar.
I have added the "Status bar is initially hidden = YES
 View controller-based status bar appearance = NO " and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

But getting the status bar.

Comment: - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
          return YES;
  }

add this method

Comment: have you write your code in viewWillappear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide iOS 7 status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar)

Comment: yes ,Written the code in viewwillAppear only

Answer (score 0):

Try it `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

I think it okey with iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
  { return YES; }

I have implemented this method in each controller.Now status bar is not displaying in ios7.

Thanks for help.