# 'invalid context 0x0' after Migration to iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, logging, ios9, xcode7, crashlytics

I've migrated the app to iOS 9, and it works as usually, but there three log messages:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Maybe helps that the next message from Crashlytics is:

```
[Crashlytics:Crash] Warning: iOS 9 workaround for binary image loading issue in place.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens when there is a definition of UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance with false in info.plist.

If you don't need this you can set the key  `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>` to true in the file manually or change `View controller-based status bar appearance` option from Info to YES.

Also, I saw some posts that state there is no problem with this. As far as I know there's no way to set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance from code, so I guess we'll have to wait until Apple will fix this issue. You can find more [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683).

Later Edit: It seems that iOS 9.1 solves this encountered errors. From last stable Xcode, running on iOS 9.1 result in no errors, while 9.0 still has the problems above.

Comment: Hmm... tried this fix and it hides the error but it still throws an exception.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is caused by this issue? Can you give more details?

Comment: [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/3577656) and in about mentioned of apple developer, apple staff have said this warning can be avoided for now and is known issue.

Answer (score 5):

Apple has stated you can safely ignore these messages
': CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. "

Check the various Apple dev forums or support areas.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I think, it is not the best solution. If I can do smth to remove these messages, I prefer to do it.