# Crashlytics: iOS 9 workaround for binary image loading issue in place

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crashlytics

I am getting this warnings with using latest crashlytics, how to get rid of them and what do they mean?

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.3.1 (79)
[Crashlytics:Crash] Warning: iOS 9 workaround for binary image loading issue in place.
```

Comment: Having same problem too :(

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540095/invalid-context-0x0-after-migration-to-ios-9

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your code, rather a message from Crashlytics about an issue they are working around in iOS9 binary loading.

Here is some info from their release note:

> Fine-tuning performance and stability
>
> In July, we were heads down making improvements to our iOS SDK,
>   bringing enhanced reporting stability and speed to your iOS apps.
>   First, we made significant improvements to logging performance that
>   increased speeds dramatically. Next, we quickly identified and worked
>   around an early iOS 9 bug and, while we were in there, we made
>   improvements to increase our defensiveness around reading binary image
>   metadata.

You can read the entire post in their July update:
https://crashlytics.com/blog/crashlytics-july-update-2015