# xCode CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, xcode7

I just updated xCode to 7.0. My code was working before but now am I getting:

> CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

In my application I have an inbox that displays an image/video once the message cell is selected. Before the messages were displaying fine but upon updating they no longer show. Is this a valid error or an Apple bug? The involved code is placed below.

**InboxTableViewController.m**

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedMessage = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // mark message as read
    NSMutableArray *readByIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"readBy"]];

    if ([readByIds containsObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]]) {
        // message has already been read. do nothing
    }else {
        // message was unread. mark it as read now.
        [readByIds addObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
        [self.selectedMessage setObject:readByIds forKey:@"readBy"];
        [self.selectedMessage saveInBackground];
    }


    NSString *fileType = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"fileType"];
    if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        // file type is image
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImage" sender:self];
    } else {
        // file type is video
        PFFile *videoFile = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"file"];
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:videoFile.url];
        self.moviePlayer.contentURL = fileUrl;
        [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

        // add it to the view controller so we can see it
        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
        [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }

}
```

...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {
        LoginViewController *lvc = (LoginViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [lvc setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        lvc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        //[segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"]) {
        ImageViewController *ivc = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [ivc setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        ivc.message = self.selectedMessage;
    }
}
```

**ImageViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *senderName = [self.message objectForKey:@"senderFullName"];
    self.navigationItem.title = senderName;

    // download image from Parse.com
    PFFile *imageFile = [self.message objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];

    //set the image view to the message image
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE` variable?

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: It could also be a bug. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/730701).

Comment: ok thank you. i reported the bug

Comment: To set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE, go to **Edit Schemes... > Run   > Arguments > Environment Variables**. 
Add Variable CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE with value 1.

Answer (score -6):

Following this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) corrected my error.

I used this in particular:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

and set these values in my info.plist

Comment: What can be that this has to do with grapichs context??

Comment: This does not answer the actual question being asked, which is about **Graphics Context**, not transport security