# CGContextSaveState, CGContextTranslateCTM, CGContextRestoreGState Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I just updated Xcode from 6.4 to 7.0 and converted my Swift to v 2.0, but I keep getting these errors every time I run my app. I've never seen these before back in version 6.4. What do these mean?

```
Sep 18 11:40:19  leap[1578] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 18 11:40:19  leap[1578] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 18 11:40:19  leap[1578] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632629/xcode-cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error), It's not important, you can ignore it.
Add this to the info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```