# how do I properly change my status bar style in swift 2/ iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm attempting to change my status bar's style to `.Light` but the previous code I implemented in swift 1.2 seems not to work anymore.. here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    }
```

now I have my `View controller-based status bar appearance` info.plist setting to YES, and reading the UIKit doc, this will negate any statusBarStyle changes and keep it at default. However when I change the setting to 'NO' and change the statusBarStyle, I get this `<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable` in my debugger.. So is this a bug in Xcode? because to change the status bar style you must change info.plist setting to NO, but when that happens.. error

Answer (score 72):

Apple have added the capability to change the status bar style in the deployment info. Simply choose 'Light'.[image: ScreenShot of Xcode]

Also set `View controller-based status bar appearance` key to `NO` in the `Info.plist`

[image: info plist]

Comment: This did not change it for me, XCode 7, iOS 9.2

Comment: Please note that this **only works** if you set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` key to `NO` in the `Info.plist`

Comment: If you select Light in 'Status Bar style' in project settings then it should automatically add this key in Info.plist file.

Comment: It should but it doesn't seem to work that way. I had to set the Info.plist key and then it worked.

Answer (score 45):

I always did this way.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //Changing Status Bar
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

        //LightContent
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

        //Default
        //return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    }
}
```

It works in any swift 2.x version. This requires that you set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your `Info.plist` file to `YES`.

Comment: Please also make sure if you use this method that you set the flag in info.plist file to make the view controller based status bar flag to yes

Comment: @real19 Yup, worked for me. Just to clear things up for beginners. To do this, just add a property in the Info.plist file, called "View controller-based status bar appearance" (Xcode will auto-complete the property name, and automatically recognize that it is a boolean), and set this property to "YES". This will make the status bar have a "light content" effect.

Comment: what if i want to change it manually or base on the context? i have a drop down notification and when this drop down shows up, i want to change status bar color. is it possible?

Comment: I can now change the status bar style at will after having implemented suggested method above in the view controller, then calling `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` from the same controller anywhere in the code. The preferredStatusBarStyle() checks if the UI uses dark or light theme and basically returns the opposite style for the status bar. Perfect.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 just add `View controller-based status bar appearance` with value `NO` to `info.plist`and then add to `ViewController`where you want:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

Comment: in iOS 10, overriding preferredStatusBarStyle doesn't appear to be enough. Need to be declared using UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle

Answer (score 7):

You can still use `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your view controller:

step 1: in the info.plist set ViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance  to YES. 
step 2: add this code to the ViewController you'd like to edit :

```
override func  preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

*** Tip: It seems to only work outside of the ViewDidLoad(), didReceiveMemoryWarning() functions.

Answer (score 6):

The change in deployment info works but despite - you need to add the
'View controller-based status bar appearance' key to plist file setting it to NO.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just add this in the AppDelegate. This option is better if you want to change it for every ViewController in the app and not have to make it different for every other VC.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    // instead of 
    // UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
    // which gives warning about deprecation in iOS 9

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's a bug in Xcode 7.0. I'm also getting the `Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0.` error when setting `View controller-based status bar appearance`

For now I'm just overriding the status bar color in every view controller.

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Comment: This not help if the content is changed so that it required to change the status bar for the same view controller programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose "light" in the deployment info, but then you also need to add the "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO.

Answer (score 4):

Here try this it might help you

First goto info.plist file and add this "View controller-based status bar appearance" as a key and set the value as NO

here below shown in the image[image]

after this come to AppDelegate.swift file and past this  `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent` line of code in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool{
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle =   UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
 return true
}
```

like this

Comment: it doesn't work when there is the navigation bar. it only works without it

Comment: @DoughnutMan does `navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default` work for you?

Comment: @Beau Nouvelle navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default this will change the navigation bar style not status bar style.

Comment: Which I believe also changes the status bar under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

For swift 3 override the preferredStatusBarStyle variable use this:

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Yeah but it's not always working and i don't know why

Comment: @AlessandroLucarini Can you try this and report back? `navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default` The above answer may work when the VC isn't embedded in a Navigation stack.

Comment: @BeauNouvelle i've solved extending NavigationController by overriding `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` when my controller is embedded in a navigation controller and by set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` when vc is presented modally.

Comment: What a freaking hassle to get this working. I'm having similar issues with some legacy code. I need to perform a blood ritual to get this stuff to work. It should really only be a single line of code. Apple....

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are great, but it's a little different now with the new updates!

`override var` now instead of `override func` for anyone confused - the gist is still the same and you still need to change your 'Info.plist':

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle 
{    
    //LightContent
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent

    //Default
    //return UIStatusBarStyle.default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it from time to time inside your app, you can use the overrides `preferredStatusBarStyle()` as mentioned before.

Just make sure, that you also call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` after calling `preferredStatusBarStyle()`, to inform IOS about it.