# Status bar style not changing for individual views - Swift 2/iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7.3

I would like to have the **default** status bar style set to some view controllers but not others. For the other views I would like to set it to lightcontent.

After taking the advice from another post I have tried setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in info.plist and add then adding the following code to viewController.swift (in an attempt to only change the status bar style of the viewcontroller in question):

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

}
```

However, this does not work despite suggestions that it does here: [how do I properly change my status bar style in swift 2/ iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674449/5657561).

What is the best solution?

Comment: I think this comment (in the question you referenced) addresses your question: "Please also make sure if you use this method that you set the flag in info.plist file to make the view controller based status bar flag to yes". If so, this question should probably be removed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Daniel if you read my question you will find that I have in fact followed this instruction and marked the flag as yes.

Comment: You may need to debug your view hierarchy and make sure that your application's rootViewController can correctly find your controllers with childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle and childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden

Comment: @markedwardmurray This wasn't part of the issue. I have solved the issue and answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this issue by firstly deleting `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist then adding this to my navigation view controller:

```
extension UINavigationController {

public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
    return self.topViewController
}

public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController? {
    return self.topViewController
}
```

Then I added this to the viewController that was connected to my navigationController:

```
override public func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

**Edit**: You can choose to ignore any warnings that xcode gives you relating to this last step - the first function can be changed from public to internal and it should still work.

Comment: what warning is Xcode generating? expect for specifically-tolerated deprecation warnings, you should always pay attention to the issues that Xcode raises.