# Hiding a statusbar in specifc viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm trying to achieve the same thing as when you show a picture in facebook where the statusBar fade. i've tried below but nothing seem to happen, what can i do in order to fade the statusBar out?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Set ImageView
    imageView.image = galleryImage

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

}

override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `info.plist` add row called `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to `NO` .

Then call the following code in `viewDidload` and it should hide with animation:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
```

After that you will be getting a warning printed in the console like :

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Just ignore it, as they said its a bug from apple and for reference see here:
 [How can I set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872650/how-can-i-set-cg-context-show-backtrace-environmental-variable)

Comment: First method doesnt seem to work? second is deprecated in ios 9

Comment: i've added above to the viewController, but the statusBar is still shown. i've added what i've done in the question