# UIBarButtons disappeared in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios

I have just upgraded one of my Apps under development to `iOS 9.2` and I have found that all navigationbar `UIBarButtons` have just disappeared and are not shown on the navigation bar.

BTW: I'm using the UIBarButton custom class called `BBBadgeBarButtonItem`
 from [here](https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem)

Update 1

Here is a snippet from the code I used to add the UIBarButtonItem

```
// Add the search button
UIImage* searchBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarButton"];
searchBtnImg = [self ipMaskedImage:searchBtnImg color:[UIColor pddAppSelectedIconColor]];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,searchBtnImg.size.width,searchBtnImg.size.height);
UIButton* searchBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[searchBtn setBackgroundImage:searchBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[searchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(_searchContent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
self.searchBarButtonItem = [[BBBadgeBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomUIButton:searchBtn];
self.searchBarButtonItem.shouldHideBadgeAtZero = YES;
self.searchBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"0";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.searchBarButtonItem;
```

Update 2

I see the following error message
`<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`

and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/1565971) it seems to be an Apple Bug

Comment: This is too broad. You need to provide more info.

Comment: I still investigating on the issue and It is not broad I don't see a reason to downvote me :(

Comment: Well I didnt downvote your question. Yes, it is still too broad to answer you question.

Comment: @Mr.T , Ok no problem. Could you please tell me what is the other information that I need to specify to not be broad?

Comment: you need to include the code that you think causes the problem, and you need to show what you have tried to make it work.

Comment: I think you are right in general , but in that case specially, I think that it wouldn't help as it is a normal code that used to work in earlier iOS versions, but in anyway I have included a sample as you told me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out, the `ImageCatalog` for random reason have make the custom BarButtonItem `Unassigned` for some unknown reason.... What a stupid thing ;(

Also, as I general note I have noticed that opening Xcode project for `iOS9.1` on newer `Xcode 7.2` or vice versa I got some of the already added images into the `ImageCatalog` to be in `Unusigned` state and the App couldn't see it until I fix that in `ImageCatalog`.