# Can't display an UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, backtrace, nsbezierpath

I'm trying to display an UIBezierPath in a view. That's the object:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0.651, green: 1.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000).setFill() 
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(15, 0, 8, 120))
rectanglePath.fill()
```

but, when run, xCode displays just a lot messages in console and none in the simulator!

I tried following these solutions [How can I set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872650/how-can-i-set-cg-context-show-backtrace-environmental-variable) but is the same (and, in their opinion, issue should be solved in with iOS 9.1).

[Here's an example code.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4712155/prova%20UIBezierPath%20che%20non%20va.zip)

Comment: I think you need understand the basics of custom drawing  on iOS fisrt. Start studyng Core Graphics library. This is a good tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

Comment: Can't I draw an UIBezierPath directly in viewController?

Comment: Remember, you draw on the View not on the ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let color = UIColor(red: 0.651, green: 1.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000).CGColor
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(15, 0, 8, 120))

    shapeLayer.path = rectanglePath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = color

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```