# Getting error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, connection

I'm using Parse and I noticed in the debugger in xcode this message:

> error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

Is there a reason why this is coming? If so what can I do about it?

Comment: It might be due to the amount of data you are requesting at once. If it's greater than a certain amount (you would need to check the amount), you'll get this message.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message because my deployment target was 8.4 and my device firmware is 9.3, fix my target to 9.3 and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message on my old iPad mini after I was trying to debug an invalid drawing context error message, setting an environment variable as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872650/how-can-i-set-cg-context-show-backtrace-environmental-variable). This resulted in multiple backtraces showing up in the Debug window, and the old iPad mini soon appeared to choke on all those traces and gave this error message. So I switched to another old device (an iPhone 5), but apparently more powerful than the old iPad mini, and the error did not show anymore. I guess the iPhone 5 had more capacity for debugging info to/from the Mac than did the old iPad mini.