# Rear camera is not working in Ipad in Xamarin forms App

Tags: ipad, camera, xamarin.forms

I am using Xam.Plugin.Media to access camera and photo gallery in my Xamarin forms app.

Its working in IPhone and in Android devices but not working in IPad with latest ios version 10.3.
The Screen will be freezed when I am calling the function to open Camera.

I tried other plugins also but the same issue. 
Front Camera is working but Rear camera is not working.

Comment: And it does work in other apps? Or the normal camera app?

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis for your reply. Yes it was working in other apps. I found the fix for this issue and posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this issue in below links.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/173

[Application freezes when trying to present rear camera on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256528/application-freezes-when-trying-to-present-rear-camera-on-ipad)

Actually I was using this code

UISlider.Appearance.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Red.ColorWithAlpha(100);

to configure some appearance of UISlider in ios. It was causing the issue.
By removing these lines, camera is working fine in both iphone and Ipad.

Comment: Actually, I have the same problem, same device, just no UISlider code. Front camera works great, on all other devices it works great, on iPad air... front cam works, back cam, nada.