# Can't hide status bar on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm building an `iOS 9` app with `horizontal` pages navigation and need to show the status bar on some pages, and hide it on others. I want to use the fade in/out animation so I have to set

`View controller-based status bar appearance = NO`

and update the status bar like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

This procedure works perfectly when navigating between pages, but I can't get rid of the status bar on launch.

I have tried setting: `Status bar is initially hidden = YES`

Adding this to the `NavigationControllers viewDidLoad:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
self.statusBarHidden = YES;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Adding this to AppDelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
application.statusBarHidden = YES;
```

Adding this to the ViewController of the initial page:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Checking the "Hide status bar" option in General->Deployment Info

And setting "Status Bar" to "None" in the linked storyboard element

But the status bar is still showing up on launch. How can I get rid of the status bar on launch without changing the value of `View controller-based status bar appearance` ?

Comment: why you don't want to change value of View controller-based status bar appearance?

Comment: I think that has to be YES in order to animate the status bar, I wasn't able to do it when it was set to NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I was doing was correct, but there was an errant `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` buried in inherited code. I grepped it, but overlooked that line...

(use `git grep StatusBar` to find lines of code in a git repo that mutate the status bar)

Also, the only code needed is:

`View controller-based status bar appearance = NO` (in plist)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

anywhere the status bar needs updating (usually in `viewWillAppear`)

Answer (score 4):

Just tick the hide status bar in project setting as below.

1. Project setting - For hiding the status bar at launch of app.

[image: Hide Status bar]

2. Add below in viewController for which you need to hide.

`- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
       return YES;
    }`

/------ UPDATE -----/

1. With tick of hide status bar
   [image: Without status bar]
2. Without tick of hide status bar
   [image: With status bar]

/------ Animate Status Bar -----/

In plist.

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Then in viewWillAppear method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Comment: I tried both of those already (forgot to mention the first), neither have an effect, together or apart

Comment: @Cbas I just tried that in demo that pasted the code for you. For verify, put a break point in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method at return yes and check your simulator for status bar. -- Do only project setting tick option and verify

Comment: The screen is black at that line. I think you have to edit your plist to recreate my situation

Comment: @Cbas - check the answer with updated screenshots. Let me know if anything is missing in my understanding. Also if you need to hide the status bar for all then go ahead for plist setting or adding the prefersStatusBarHidden method in all vc.

Comment: As stated in the OP, I can't animate the status bar in and out with this technique...

Comment: @Cbas - you or your question didn't said anything about animating the hide/show of status bar so for next time pls be clear with your question.

Comment: "I want to use the fade in/out animation so I have to..."

Answer (score 1):

```
changing plist file : 

set Status bar is initially hidden = YES

add row: View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: This is working fine before iPhone 11 or iPhone Pro max how can we hide in iPhone 11

Answer (score 0):

Goto Targets->General->Deployment Info: and under that select Hide Status Bar option.

Comment: in Xcode Press cmd+1 then you will see Proejcts and Targets tab so select Target

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve what you are looking for you need set in the `app.plist`file:

`Status bar is initially hidden` to `YES`

`View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`

Then in every view controller to **show** it

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

or to **hide** it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: if I put `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` in viewDidLoad of my view controller, it has no effect and the status bar shows up. The plist values are already set

Comment: Are you overriding `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden; ` My guess is there may be something this behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried just removing that method from the view-controller?