# How to hide Status Bar on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, status

In my project I able to hide status bar on iPhone.

But it doesn’t work for my iPad How can I hide Status Bar on my iPad?

Comment: What did you try for hiding status bar on iPad?Show your coding.

Answer (score 4):

you should override the method,

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

in every `viewcontroller` if you have not making setting in `info.plist` for hiding it.

if you want to manage in `info.plist` then,

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

You can check the screenshot below

[image]

screenshot reference : [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-status-bar), you can refer this post also btw.

Answer (score 4):

Objective C:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
 return YES;
}
```

Swift 4:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
 return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and I have set info.plist with what Charlie Fish showed, but it's not help.

I fixed by changing TARGETS->Deployment info->Devices to iPad, then run Xcode.