# How to hide status bar in swift?

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios13

I used the following code to hide the status bar and it works fine
But it works until I go to another page. That is, if I go to another page and go back, it won't work anymore
Does anyone know why?
Can anyone help me?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        if self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57035991/6677134) out

Comment: @Sayooj I want the status bar not to be hidden when the navigation bar is not hidden and this awnser is not for my question

Comment: When you come back and swipe again on navigation bar does it hide the navigation bar?

Comment: yes my friend @Sayooj

Comment: I've put up an example project [here](https://github.com/sayoojkrishnan/TabBarExample). Check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code ...:)

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: That's true, but if I go to another viewcontroller and go back, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

just add this one

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
// call this func to force preferredStatusBarStyle to be read again.
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can hide it from `info.plist` with option `initially hides status
  bar` giving value `true`

this will hide status bar for your entire app

- Then show it to the specific `viewcontrollers` with following code

  ```
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return false
  }
  ```