# Center VStack vertically?

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("dklf")
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Why is the VStack not aligned in the middle of the Screen vertically?

[image]

Comment: That is accurate, you're forgetting to account for the status bar that is being used at the top. Try disabling your status bar in the app and it should then center.

Comment: If you need the status bar u can subtract its size twice to the height and it will be centered.

Answer (score 1):

`UIScreen.main.bounds` does not account for the Safe Area, so this is what you probably wanted:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("dklf")
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ok thanks. I don't understand, why this blue border isn't at the top. If I add **.statusBar(hidden: true)** after the VStack, the blue border stays also there.

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Color.yellow
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: To hide the status bar check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-status-bar