# Change style of statusBar

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm trying to change the style of statusBar, and I tried to use the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    //2
    self.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent)
    //3
    if self.respondsToSelector(#selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)){
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work, can anyone help me out.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674315/how-do-i-properly-change-my-status-bar-style-in-swift-2-ios-9

Comment: There are tons of these duplicate answers about status bar...

Comment: there are many related answer already posted in Stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235401/uistatusbarstyle-not-working-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

To your Info.plist file add this key-value pair:

```
 UIStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

> The default (black) value is UIStatusBarStyleDefault.

Comment: Also define for IOS 7 in :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924345/how-to-change-status-bar-style-during-launch-on-ios-7

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the "View Controller based status Bar apperance" to NO in you Info.plist.

Another option is:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

In your View Controller.

Comment: Not copied, but the same solution.

Comment: @Dejan Skledar: Kindly provide a link to the answer instead of copying and pasting it.

Comment: Since when is my experience copying another answer?